# How to solve "could not find audio decoder component 64766938 for registration"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I remove this "could not find audio decoder component 64766938 for registration" which is shown in nslog?

Comment: Can you provide some more information  (preferably the piece of code causing the error). Not everybody knows component 64766938 by heart.

Answer (score 0):

I remember running into this problem when loading audio files, and I had to re-convert them into .CAF files using Quicktime.

Not sure what the underlying issue is, whether it's something we're doing wrong or an Apple bug, but it's certainly a terse error. :-\

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. but if u have any solution to remove this from nslog plzz inform me. thanks again.